# Как в Vue привязать обработчик к динамически создаваемой ссылке?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Динамический получаю сообщение:

```
this.$http.post('/page', {'number' : '123'})
    .then(response => {
        this.windowText = response.data.message;
});
```

В сообщении есть ссылка с определенным классом, например:

```
response.data.message = 'Какой-то текст с <a class="action" href="/test">сыылкой</a>';
```

В шаблоне просто выводится:

```
<div v-html="windowText"></div>
```

Теперь вопрос: как мне создать обработчик для ссылок с классом `action`, который обрабатывал бы клик по этой ссылке?

К редактированию `response.data.message` у меня доступа нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как водится, сделать это можно не одним способом, но используем [`Vue.nextTick()`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick):
Каллбэк, передаваемый в эту функцию, будет вызван после того, как ожидаемые работы с DOM будут разрешены.

```js
function linkHandler(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.info(`Хочу перейти на ${this.href}!`);
}

let app = new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  data: {
    windowText: `Default page`
  },
  methods: {
    load: _ => {
      app.windowText = 'Какой-то текст с <a class="action" href="/test">сыылкой</a>';
      Vue.nextTick()
        .then(_ => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a.action')).forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', linkHandler)));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div v-html="windowText"></div><br />
  <input type='button' @click='load' value='Загрузить новую страницу!' />
</div>
```

Comment: Т.е. Мой ответ не верный ты решил еще свой написать :) жжешь

Comment: @Orange_shadow, Я добавил информации, приправил наглядным примером. Ваш ответ вполне имеет право быть (хотя где Вы увидели хуквери в метках - не знаю).

Comment: Забей, на меня действует погода за окном )

Answer (score 0):

Напишу с использованием `jQuery`:

1. В `mounted` просто ставишь `live` событие:

   ```
   {
       data : function(){
         return {...}
       },
       mounted:function(){
          $(document).on('click','a. action',function(){/*твой обработчик*/})
       }
   }
   ```
2. Второй способ:

   ```
   this.$http.post('/page', {'number' : '123'})
       .then(response => {
           this.windowText = response.data.message;
           Vue.nextTick(function(){
               $('a.action').on('click',function(){/*твой обработчик*/})
           }) 
   });
   ```